# How to read from/with Optional<Reader>?

Tags: java, java-8, io, option-type

I wrote a short test Class for testing (who would've guessed) and cannot find a way to read from an `Optional<BufferedReader>`.
Maybe I'm not familiar enough with I/O, but I tried creating a `BufferedReader` to read a file and pass it to the `Optional<BufferedReader>`, but it doesn't let me.
Casting doesn't work either. So, how can I fix this idea?

```java
File file = new File(myFile);
Optional<BufferedReader> reader;
```

This doesn't work:

```java
reader.read(new FileReader(myFile).read());
```

or

```java
reader = new FileReader(myFile).read();
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is the purpose of that optional?

Comment: `Optional<BufferedReader> reader;` is an uninitialized variable, there is nothing to read from. Apparently, you want to read from `myFile`, so just do that and remove the obsolete variable.

Comment: I appreciate the accept; and welcome to upvote levels ;-)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply!
I had to use an Optional for a piece of code for a work project. There's a more advanced programmer in my team who wrote the basic "frame" for my project so I only had to fill in the logic so to speak.
He used the Optional reader for something I don't quite understand and he can't quite explain ... But your answers helped me a bit in foguring out what my problem was

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File file = new File(myFile);
Optional<BufferedReader> reader;
```

Simply, that doesn't make real sense. The point of Optional is to express: you have "something", and that can either be present, or missing. But you can't use it to "keep reading" directly from that Optional object. Optional is just a wrapper, that helps you avoiding passing `null` around.

From that point of view, an Optional isn't a source for reading. If at all, you can use the Optional, so that others can determine: there is an reader, so lets read from that reader. In other words: instead of asking `if (reader == null)` you could do `if (readerOptional.isPresent())`. And then you could do `someReader = readerOptional.get()`.

But as said, there is really (not much) sense in doing so.